# Equivalent of `readlink` on SFTP

Tags: shell, sftp

When I log into an SFTP server through the shell using `sftp`, I can navigate using the usual `cd` etc commands.

- One command I use frequently outside of SFTP is `readlink -f $FILE` to print the full path of $FILE.
- I use this to copy & paste file paths, e.g. into scripts.

Question: Is there an equivalent to `readlink` in SFTP?

I found in the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp) that I can show the current directory using `pwd`, but its neither just the path nor does it allow me to point to other directories than cwd, as far as I can tell.

Thanks

Comment: There's is a `readlink` in SFTP (as in a protocol), but there's no `readlink` in `sftp` (as in OpenSSH SFTP client) – Other SFTP clients may have such feature (my Windows WinSCP does show link targets – Not that it helps you – Just a proof that it is technically possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by @MartinPrikryl, that's not possible with the stock sftp client, despite symbolic links being supported by the sftp protocol.

An alternative is `sshfs`:

```
sshfs user@host:/ /some/dir

... use your regular shell commands on the files from /some/dir ...

fusermount -u /some/dir
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work when combined with a mount namespace, so you'll have to make do with the icky and yucky **setuid** `fusermount` (as used by sshfs by default).